# Calling another C++ method from jni method in ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

First, I have a JNIEXPORT method look like this:

```
  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_app_osap_Native_nativeProcessImage(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring imagePath){
  // ...
   handle(data);
 }
```

Then I write another method in the same cpp file:

```
 void handle(int data[]){

 }
```

But I get this error when compile source code:

```
   'handle' was not declared in this scope
```

Please tell me what my problem is and how I can solve it. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't use headers, you need to declare handle function before the JNI function. Or, you may start to use headers that will contain the declarations of the functions and then include it in your cpp file. Like:

test.h:

```
void handle(int data[]);
```

test.cpp

```
#include test.h
```

Don't forget to add the header to your module in your Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := path/to/test.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := path/to/test.h     #This is the header file you created
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: I'd suggest creation and use of a header file, it is what other people would expect.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 Though you are right, he looks like he is a new starter and I did not want to make things more complicated. Anyway, I will edit my solution.

Comment: @user2359247 Thanks very much, I tried to declare handle function before the JNI and it worked. And I'll consider header file approach. Since I'm a ndk newbie, so there are a lot of things that I don't know.

Comment: I would suggest finding a good C++ book and reading it together with an NDK book. Since you need C++ for NDK, learning how it works will help you a lot while learning NDK. Good luck.

Comment: How to include extra files with gradle?